# Migration fron Xcode 7 to Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, swift3, migration, xcode7, xcode8

Today after migration I receive this kind of the error:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '__entitlements'

I already clean project and derived data folders. Additionally I check migration changes and they are connected with swift language versions and                 **libstdc++.dylib** to **libc++.tbd**.

Could you please suggest any other steps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation of the issue. I understand that this issue was due to the missing **Linker Flags**.

```
Linker Flags:
-ObjC
-lz
-lstdc++
```